# last version of (gem) working with rails 2.3

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to know what version of a specific gem is working with the last Ruby on Rails 2.3.x (2.3.13 as I am writing) and which one is the last supported officially.

Given a fictional examplegem "Foo" which runs in version 3beta with rails 2.3 but the development officially support rails 2.3 only until "Foo 2.5" so someone could try to use Foo 3beta but shall not bother the development with bugreports because of incompatibility with rails 2.3

I hope everyone understands my intention, so just edit, comment or answer.

Example:
gem "Foo", "~> 2.5" #but "= 3beta" worked for me, see my blogposg at http://example.com/

**The List:**

- [RSpec-Rails](http://rubygems.org/gems/rspec-rails/versions/1.3.4): `gem "rspec-rails", "~> 1.3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [github](http://www.github.com) and find the repository of the gem then check out the tags of different versions viewing the README. A quick google search works as well. I do not know of a resource that gives the information you are requesting.

Comment: I wanted this to grow to this resource. Everyone who finds a gem that is not working with his rails 2.3, shall write it down here as an answer or comment with the results of his research so that others that have to start a new project using old rails, or just extending an old project, don't have to do all the work again. Instead the Google and find this list. That was my idea. I did it here and not in my own blog because of the fact, that the community is much bigger here and the list would be on topic.